# Power BI: What-If parameter with a date filter

Tags: powerbi, datefilter

I need to display data on a table that will display data from six days ago based on the date selected on the filter. For example, if the date selected on the filter is "2020/06/30", I need the table to display data from "2020/06/29", "2020/06/28", "2020/06/27", "2020/06/26", "2020/06/25", "2020/06/24".

I tried to use a What-If parameter, but I can not link the parameter to the date column on my table. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You have separate table for Date slicer and Data? or same table?

Comment: @R_R, I do have a separate table for the data and the date. I am using a calendar table for date filtering.

Comment: Date and Data table connected?

Comment: Yes, they are connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your purpose, You basically need a disconnected Calendar table. You can create a separate **custom table** for all dates as below-

> Considering your calendar table name **Dates**

> Considering your fact table name **your_fact_table_name**

```
Dates_disconnected =
SELECTCOLUMNS(
    Dates,
    "Date",Dates[Date]
)
```

Now, create your **Date** sclicer using the new custom table **Dates_disconnected**.

Finally, create a **Measure** as below in your **Base** table-

```
filter = 

VAR current_row_date = MIN(your_fact_table_name[date])
VAR selected_date = SELECTEDVALUE(Dates_disconnected[Date])
VAR selected_start_date = SELECTEDVALUE(Dates_disconnected[Date]) - 5

RETURN 
IF(
    current_row_date < selected_date && current_row_date>= selected_start_date,
    "No",
    "Yes"
)
```

> considered last 5 day in the above measure. you can adjust the range.

The above Measure will give you some output as below-

[image]

You can see Previous 5 day (considering selected date in slicer) is showing **No** and all other row is showing **Yes**. Now, just apply a visual level filter using the measure **filter** and filter out all rows having **Yes** in the row.

Comment: After doing this, is it possible to group on the measure and then get totals? Like total rows per group?

Answer (score 0):

You can set your filter on your visual (or page) like below. This is possible when you set it to advanced filter.

[image]

If you do not want a static filtern, you can use the Slicer visual as below:

[image]

It will filter your other visuals

You can also use Befor-after or between
[image]

Comment: This one isn't ideal because I need the parameter to change the number of days relative to the date selected on the slicer.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Much appreciated.