# How to use a date slicer as a Parameter in a filter Power BI

Tags: powerbi, slicers

I'm trying to use the max date of a date slicer as a parameter to compare dates and filter my table for calculations in Power BI but this doesn't filter properly.
Here is my max date based on a Datetime column in my Table:

```
Max Created Date = CALCULATE(
        MAX( Users[Created] ),
        ALLSELECTED( Users[Created])
    )
```

I then use this to compare dates:

```
VAR Lastmonth = EOMONTH([Max Created Date],-1)+1
VAR eom = [Max Created Date]
VAR VideoSessionTable = SELECTCOLUMNS(
         FILTER(Videos,
        Videos[Date] >= Lastmonth && Videos[Date] <= eom && 
        Videos[TotalSecondsWatched] >= 180), "Id", Videos[Id])
return
CALCULATE(COUNT(Users[Id]),
    FILTER(Users,
            AND(
                OR(AND(Users[Departed Date] <= eom, Users[Departed Date] >= Lastmonth),
                 ISBLANK(Users[Departed Date]))
                ,
                Users[UserOrganisation Id] IN VideoSessionTable)
    ))
```

vs (SELECTED VALUE ON A SINGLE DATE SLICER) based on a date Table
(I have followed this thread to do so [Power BI: What-If parameter with a date filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64152723/power-bi-what-if-parameter-with-a-date-filter))

```
DateForSecondSlicer = SELECTEDVALUE(Dates[Dates])
```

```
VAR Lastmonth = [DateForSecondSlicer]
var eom = EOMONTH([DateForSecondSlicer],0)+1
VAR VideoSessionTable = SELECTCOLUMNS(
                    FILTER(Videos,
                            Videos[Date] >= Lastmonth && Videos[Date] < eom && Videos[TotalSecondsWatched] >= 180), "Id", Videos[Id])
return
CALCULATE(COUNT(Users[Id]),
    FILTER(Users,
            AND(
                OR(AND(Users[Departed Date] < eom , Users[Departed Date] >= Lastmonth),
                 ISBLANK(Users[Departed Date]))
                ,
                Users[Id] IN VideoSessionTable)
    ))
```

The behaviour expected is when I change the slicer, it counts the number of licensed members.
On the left, I'm using the Max value as a parameter, on the right the single SELECTED VALUE() as a parameter. The right output is the expected output.

[Ouput tables][1]

Notice the totals are the same but when I count on the left I have only 7 ones.
I have done it with a single value selection instead(SELECTEDVALUE(date) and this work.
This is not really the slicer I want to use.
Is there a way to make this work?

Here I recreated the issue:

Power Bi : https://app.powerbi.com/groups/me/reports/42597a8e-0ca1-48d1-b7f6-c572502006b6/ReportSection

Comment: There is not a lot of information to go on here. Please expand your post by adding e.g. sample data from your fact table, and a small sample of data that explains what you want to accomplish from using your date slicer.

Comment: @Marcus Sorry I thought the output was available, now you can see a screenshot of the output. I'll try to recreate and provide sample data.

Comment: @Marcus For some reason I can't share screenshots. I shared the power bi test workbook with the same issue